# A maths function

Tags: mathematics

I am using a function, and the outputs are below. What function am I using?

function($0+0$) = 0

function($73942856-628529469252$) = -1

function($1 + 1$) = 1

function($1+2$) = 1

function($528^0$) = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be

> The $sign$ function, which maps positive values to 1, negative values to -1, and 0 to 0.

Comment: Correct! Well done

Answer (score 0):

I propose

> $$f(x) = 0.09388 + 0.62997atan(x) - 0.09388cos(x) + 0.186498sin(x)$$

Comment: Good try, but the question has already been answered

Comment: Oh my... this answer, I swear, hahah. Just a quick question: by $\rm atan$${}$$(x)$ do you mean $\rm arctan$${}$$(x)$? :P

Comment: @user477343 yep

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. To be honest, I sometimes can't be bothered writing $\arctan$,so I quite prefer $\rm atan$ :P